# Still getting undefined to a property in node with react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-redux

I have three different components that within them are using a component called `StripeCheckout` and one of the properties of `StripeCheckout` is `description` which I currently have as a string:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../actions";

class SunnySampler extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <StripeCheckout
          name='Microurb Farms'
          amount={this.props.amount}
          description='Sunny Sampler Box'
          shippingAddress
          billingAddress={false}
          zipCode={true}
          token={(token, amount) =>
            this.props.handleToken(token, this.props.amount)
          }
          stripeKey={process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(SunnySampler);
```

`SunnySampler` is just one of the three components making use of `StripeCheckout`. Each has its own `amount` property dynamically coded and passed down to the express api and yet I cannot seem to pass down the `description` property successfully.

The challenge also is that each `description` property is different depending on which component was selected.

So I was able to pass in the `amount` dynamically here:

```
const tiers = [
  {
    title: "Half pound boxes",
    price: "10",
    description: [
      "Sunflower Shoots",
      "Pea Shoots",
      "Radish Shoots",
      "Broccoli Shoots",
    ],
    buttonText: <HalfPound amount={1000} />,
    buttonVariant: "outlined",
  },
  {
    title: "Grasses",
    subheader: "Tray",
    price: "15",
    description: ["Wheatgrass", "Barleygrass"],
    buttonText: <Grasses amount={1500} />,
    buttonVariant: "contained",
  },
  {
    title: "Sunny Sampler Box",
    price: "20",
    description: [
      "6oz Sunflower",
      "2oz Broccoli",
      "3oz Sweet Pea",
      "2oz Radish",
    ],
    buttonText: <SunnySampler amount={2000} />,
    buttonVariant: "outlined",
  },
];
```

this is inside of `Dashboard.js`, then in my action creator I pass it in like so:

```
export const handleToken = (token, amount) => async (dispatch) => {
  const res = await axios.post("/api/stripe", { token, amount });

  dispatch({ type: FETCH_USER, payload: res.data });
};
```

Inside each of those payment type of components it looks like so:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actions from "../actions";

class SunnySampler extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <StripeCheckout
          name='Microurb Farms'
          amount={this.props.amount}
          description='Sunny Sampler Box'
          shippingAddress
          billingAddress={false}
          zipCode={true}
          token={(token, amount) =>
            this.props.handleToken(token, this.props.amount)
          }
          stripeKey={process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE_KEY}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(null, actions)(SunnySampler);
```

and finally my backend api:

```
const keys = require("../config/keys");
const stripe = require("stripe")(keys.stripeSecretKey);

module.exports = (app) => {
  app.post("/api/stripe", async (req, res) => {
    const { amount, token } = req.body;
    // const description = req.body.data.description;
    const charge = await stripe.charges.create({
      amount: amount,
      currency: "usd",
      source: token.id,
    });

    console.log(charge);
  });
};
```

I tried taking the same approach I took to the `amount` property with the `description` property and variations of it and I am still getting `undefined`.

Originally, inside the action creator I had passed in description to it and then inside the handleToken I had passed in `this.props.description` and then inside the api route on the backend I had `req.body.description` which should have worked, but I got `undefined`.

When I console log `req.body` I see in the data structure `description: null`, despite having passed a string into the `description` property inside of `StripeCheckout` component. I cannot explain why that is.

Comment: Where and what are you expecting the value NOT to be undefined?

Comment: @Kiran, so originally, inside the action creator I had passed in `description` to it and then inside the `handleToken` I had passed in `this.props.description` and then inside the api route on the backend I had `req.body.description` which should have worked, but I got undefined and I am unclear as to why.

Comment: One reason, seeing your commented code in the api route could be that you were accessing `req.body.data.description` instead of `req.body.description`

Comment: @Kiran, I did also try `req.body.description` and still got `undefined`.